# Select 2 option not Selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select 2 box for displaying some form options. Data is coming from an ajax request and i am appending the options to the select2. The problem is when i append the options i do see them in the drop down list but can not select them.

Here is the code i am using.

```
    $('#vehiclegroup-vehiclegroup_clientid').on('change',
    $('#vehiclegroup-vehiclegroup_clientid'),function(){

    var clientType = $('#vehiclegroup-vehiclegroup_clienttype').val();
    var company = $('#vehiclegroup-vehiclegroup_clientid').val();
    $.ajax({

        divId: divids[1],
        url: "index.php?r=vehiclegroup/getvehiclegroups",
        data: {'company': company , 'clientType': clientType},
        method: 'GET',
        success: populateUser

    })
});
```

The code for the populateUser function

```
  function populateUser(data)
  {


   $(this.divId).empty();

   var newUser;
   var userList = data['list'];

   for (var client in userList )
   {
     newUser = "<option value=" + client + ">" +
        userList[client] + "</option>";

     $(this.divId).append(newUser);


   }
}
```

I am using the same function for another select2 box on the same page and its working fine.

Edit:

My Select 2 initialization code is as follows

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'vehiclegroup_parentid')->widget(Select2::classname(),
        [
            'data' => [],
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select SubGroup Name'],
            'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
        ]
    )->label('SubGroup'); ?>
```

Comment: where are you initializing .select2() pluging, could you post the same here.

Comment: I am using the Yii widget class in view.

Comment: ok, quick check, check if you are initializing select 2 aftr you ajax not befor

Comment: Yes the ajax request is after the select2 has been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was not able to select the first option, first i needed to select any other option and then it became selectable. I searched a little and it is because you need to trigger the change even after appending options.

```
   $(this.divId).select2().trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your select2 initialization

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'vehiclegroup_parentid')->widget(Select2::classname(),
    [
        'data' => [],
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select SubGroup Name'],
        'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
    ]
)->label('SubGroup'); ?>
```

is after your ajax request complete not before that. Your problem is your select2 is initialize before you append option to select2 and hence select2 will not recognize your options added later on.